# JavaScript:regex find Datatime and serial in an text

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm very beginner in Regular expression so I have an paragraph this paragraph contain two required numbers the first one Serial [fp,sp,tp,fop] lets assume length of

> fp=3,sp=2 or 1 ,tp=3 TO 5, fop=2 TO 5

and all of them will be number separated by - will be like this

> 432-32-2356-12

and the datetime will be like

> 23-aug-2017

for example this is a text that contain my requirements

> Hello every one today 23-aug-2017 I joined stackoverflow community via
>   this serial 432-32-2356-12

then How can I find the both numbers I tried but didn't get correct result and this  is my regularex in JavaScript `/(\d[\d\.]*)/g` 
also it's my code

```
var serial=p.match(/(\d[\d\.]*)/g);
var date=p.match(/(\d[\d\.]*)/g);
```

please any help or suggestion in pure javascript

Comment: You have rules. Just follow them: [`(\d+-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{4})|(\d{3}-\d{1,2}-\d{3,5}-\d{2,5})`](https://regex101.com/r/qkTIz1/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your date regex, you completely ignored string part.

```js
var text = 'Hello every one today 23-aug-2017 I joined stackoverflow community via this serial 432-32-2356-12';
var re1 = /(\d{3})\-(\d|\d{2})\-(\d{3,5})\-(\d{2,5})/;
console.log(text.match(re1)[0]);
var re2 = /(\d{2})\-([a-z]{3})-(\d{4})/i;
console.log(text.match(re2)[0]);
```

Comment: it's right but how can I get just the first result I mean only 432-32-2356-12 and 23-aug-2017

Comment: @AlanNamaYosuf, use index `[0]`, I have edited my post